# Hive SQL, how to have multiple columns in group_concat?

Tags: hive, hql, impala, group-concat

I have data that looks like this:

```
Customer       DUNS         Employees
   A            1              60
   A            2             100
   A            3              15
   A            4              40
```

What I am wanting is this:

```
Customer        NEW CONCAT FIELD
   A            1:60, 2:100, 3:15, 4:40
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Select 
 Customer
,group_concat(cast(DUNS as string)) as DUNS
,group_concat(cast(Employees as string)) as 'Emps'
From MyTable
group by Customer
```

And here are the results:

```
Customer        DUNS           EMPS
   A            1, 2, 3, 4     60,100,15,40
```

I am just really struggling to combine these into one field.  I find MySQL syntax that looks like what I need, but it doesn't work in my cloudera/Impala editor.

For the life of me I cannot find where this has been done before, but I'm sure it as somewhere.  How do I edit this query to get that 'NEW CONCAT FIELD'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `concat` the 2nd and 3rd field and use `collect_list` on the new field

```
select Customer,collect_list(duns_employees) as duns_employees_list from
(
    select Customer,CONCAT(DUNS,':',Employees) as duns_employees from table
) a
group by Customer;
```